# Set Scrollbar Style of Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I make the scrollviewer in my textbox style use my scrollbar style?

```
    <Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">                    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="_rct" Stroke="#FFA8AFBE" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Fill="White" />
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#FFA8AFBE" Background="White">                   
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="6"  x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My scrollbar style:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff007eb1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>      
</Style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scrollbar style?"  Whether a scrollbar is shown?  Or something else?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Unfortunately, I have no idea either.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do as following:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource MyScrollBarStyle}"></Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the ScrollViewer template.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollBar 
        x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Minimum="0.0"
        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay}"
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"         
        Cursor="Arrow"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
        Style="{StaticResource MyScrollBarStyle}"/>
    <ScrollBar 
        x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Minimum="0.0"
        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay}"
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
        Cursor="Arrow"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"
        Style="{StaticResource MyScrollBarStyle}"/>
    <ScrollContentPresenter 
        x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>
    <Rectangle 
        x:Name="Corner"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Or you could remove the style's key so that it gets applied to all ScrollBar controls. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5,

```
<TextBox  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
 <TextBox.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle1}">
                            </Style>
  </TextBox.Resources>
```

To define your own scroll bar style [visit here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076(v=vs.95).aspx)